# How to get random tuples from database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm working on creating a online quiz program. I want to change questions every time new user logging in. Is there any way to get questions from database randomly?

I have tried rand() function but it generates same question again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NEWID()` of MySQL. The SQL SELECT `NEWID()` function returns the random row. GUID in memory for each row. By definition, the GUID is unique and random so, you will get the perfect random record.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY NEWID()
```

TO know more you can [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/software-testing/cc441928(v=msdn.10))